# How to use screen with mysql cli?

Tags: mysql, gnu-screen

Here is what is happening. I'm using debian with KDE. I open Konsole.
I use ssh to log into my amazon server. All of the following commands are done in the Konsole whiled logged into the amazon server. The screen I get when I log it I will call "original" screen:

1. I type screen and, as expected, I get a new detached screen
2. I log into mysql
3. Now I want to go to the "original". For this I would press Cntrl+a,d. However when I'm logged into mysql, it simply exits mysql (it logs me out) and does not send me back to the "original" screen.

Comment: Now I've got it. I know Konsole quite well. I think your question is likely answerable now. But just to be sure, can you post your `.screenrc` from the remote Amazon server?

Comment: I think I don't have one. As far as I understand .screenrc you create if you want to change some configurations. And I never did. There is nothing in my home and my etc folder only contains the example file.

Comment: when typing "screen" you should not get a "detached" screen, you should be inside screen in a new session with a new terminal active.

Comment: Yes. You are right. My bad. Sorry.